# Xarray requesting "compute()" for a boolean array

Tags: dask, python-xarray

In xarray version 2023.7.0, if you open a NetCDF with `open_mfdataset`,

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('my_file.nc')
```

And then you want to find the max,

```
ds.where(ds["d2fd"] == ds["d2fd"].max(), drop=True)
```

you get the message:

**KeyError**: *'Indexing with a boolean dask array is not allowed. This will result in a dask array of unknown shape. Such arrays are unsupported by Xarray.Please compute the indexer first using .compute()'*

You don't get the message if you open with `open_dataset`. In previous versions of xarray this worked. I think `compute()` can refer to `dask`, but I don't know how to solve it. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this issue here: https://github.com/hainegroup/oceanspy/issues/332

Calling `.where` with `drop=True`, silently evaluates the data.

Now you just have to additionally call `.compute()`:

```py
ds.where(ds["d2fd"] == ds["d2fd"].max().compute(), drop=True)
```